# AWS RDS Parameter Group formulas

Tags: parameters, amazon-rds, formula

The AWS RDS parameter group formulas seem buggy.  I find this hard to believe, so I am hoping someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.  My question is regarding the formula syntax, not what the parameter should be.

I am trying to set the Aurora MySQL parameter max_connections.   The default given in the parameter group provided by AWS is...

GREATEST({log(DBInstanceClassMemory/805306368)*45},{log(DBInstanceClassMemory/8187281408)*1000})

Pretty clever.  It sets the value based on the instance size, as it should.  However, I wish to be slightly more aggressive on the small instances that we do functional tests on.

I have tried the following.  And get this same attached error every time when I try and save it.
[image: error given]

1. Tried to add another parameter to the GREATEST function. To have a minimum of 200.

GREATEST({log(DBInstanceClassMemory/805306368)*45},{log(DBInstanceClassMemory/8187281408)*1000},200)
This gives error.

2. Increase the multipliers.  (I changed 45 to 46)   Got same error.  This is where I started getting skeptical there actually was an error.
3. I hard coded a number, which worked.  Then pasted the EXACT SAME default formula AWS provided back into the parameter to save it back again.  Got the error.

Based on this it appears to me that AWS has an error somewhere.  It doesn't even like their own formula.  It gives the same error in both cluster parameter group and the instance parameter group.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's a small trick here:

You will not be able to change or input manually values with "log formula", but you can return the original value of the parameter (inside the DB parameter group) using the RESET button:

[image]

This way it will reset the default value using the "log" formula.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is AWS won't let you use "log" in your own formulas. You can make a roughly equivalent formula using just memory size division though i.e. GREATEST({DBInstanceClassMemory/9868951},200) would have minimum effectively of 200 max but then scale for instance memory size. Adjust the divisor to whatever is appropriate, also note the math on this is a little vague because DBInstanceClassMemory afaik is an internal value that isn't necessarily the instance type memory size as it subtracts out some amount of memory that RDS retains.

Support for this is requested within AWS though.